# Javascript error at start

Tags: javascript, asp.net, error-handling

When i start the page it gives me this error. I can press no but then the code doesnt work.

[image]

the code is how do i fix this error??
by the way the button browse opens the fileupload but that is in c#
 Thanks in advance.

```
    <%@ control language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="Web_Controls_SOLATDFileChooser, App_Web_ivmyhbca" %>

<!--2012-05-11 TP : Redesign da página web -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/CMM/InternetFace.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    div.fileinputs
    {
        position: relative;
    }

    div.fakefile
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    input.file
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function clear() {
        document.getElementById("<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>").value = "";
        document.getElementById("<%=txtFileName.ClientID %>").value = "";
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function uploadFileChange() {
    document.getElementById("<%=txtFileName.ClientID %>").value = document.getElementById("<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>").value;
    }

</script>

<table width="500px">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle">
            <div class="fileinputs">
                <!-- Upload file invisivel-->
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" class="file" runat="server"
                    onchange="uploadFileChange();" />
                <!-- button e textbox falsas para poder dar syles-->
                <div class="fakefile">
                    <!--textbox onde está o path do ficheiro-->
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFileName" CssClass="textbox"  runat="server"
                        Width="300px" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <!-- button de browse-->
                    <asp:Button ID="btnBrowse" runat="server" Text="Procurar..."
                        ForeColor="White" Height="21px" />
                    <!--button para apagar o path ja que a textbox esta em read-only para prevenir erros-->
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Height="21px" CssClass="btnSubmit" Text="Apagar" ForeColor="White"
                        OnClientClick="clear();" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Misplaced `;` here `clear() {;`, `document` is misspelt & quote the IDs `...ById("<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>")`

Comment: i fixed everything you guys said but it still doesn´t work.

Comment: Looks like quoted IDs are still absent, if it still fails please post a demo url or the rendered output

Comment: no, not everything: and you should not change your original post with our suggestions. imho it makes our post useless and/or confused for newcomers.

Comment: OK i won't change from now on sorry, the problem was resolved somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have many errors in that code

1. Extra `;` after `{` (in both functions *(before you updated)*
2. `documente` instead of `document`  *(before you updated)*
3. You call an undefined function `UploadFileChange` (you called it `UploadFielChange`) *(before you updated)*
4. No quotes inside `getElementById()`

and as a sidenote it's useless to close a `script` block and then reopen another one on next line. Both the functions can be enclosed in the same `script` block

Answer (score 2):

"documente" is not correct, should be "document" instead

As well, maybe the interpreter has problems with the ";" right after "{", which is useless

Rgds.

Comment: The interpreter *will* have problems with the `;`. Furthermore, he'll need to quote the ID's spat out by ASP.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `;` after `{` and change `documente`to `document`. Also, some quotations are missing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function clear() {
document.getElementById('<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>').value ="";
document.getElementById('<%=txtFileName.ClientID %>').value ="";
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function uploadFielChange() {
document.getElementById('<%=txtFileName.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>').value;

}
</script>
```

And please notice that `uploadFielChange` != `UploadFielChange`, so you got to change this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `documente` throughout your code where I suspect you want `document`. Try changing that first off.

You have an extra `;` at the end of this line: `function uploadFielChange() {;`

Finally, you need to quote the IDs, as Alex K. pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your server template engine does not work:

```
<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>
```

is no valid JS. Check your code with http://www.jslint.com/!

Comment: So, show us the rendered HTML since you show us the error of the rendered HTML/JS. Or does this error occur without rendered HTML???

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ";" after the opening brackets of the functions and replace "documente" with "document"

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function clear() {
document.getElementById(<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>).value ="";
document.getElementById(<%=txtFileName.ClientID %>).value ="";
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function uploadFielChange() {
document.getElementById(<%=txtFileName.ClientID %>).value = document.getElementById(<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>).value;

}
</script>
...
```